# Error while deleting object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects, riot.js

I get undefined error while deleting object from list of objects.

Html:

```
<div>
<p each="{holidayListSecondPart, i in this.holidayListSecondPart}">
    <span id="{holidayListSecondPart.description}">{holidayListSecondPart.description}</span>

    <span id="delete{i+1}" onclick="{remove}">delete</span>

    <span id="editHoliday{i+1}" onclick="{editHoliday}">edit</span>
</p>
</div>
```

js code:

```
remove(e){
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
    console.log('DataMixin.data before delete ', DataMixin.data.holidayList);
    self.deletingId = e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild.id;
    for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(DataMixin.data.holidayList).length; i++){
        if(self.deletingId == DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1].reason){
            console.log("delete ID matched: ", i+1);
            console.log('ID to be deleted is: ' , DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1]);
            delete DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1];
        }
    }
    console.log('DataMixin.data after delete ', DataMixin.data.holidayList);
}
```

List of object looks like this:

[image: List of objects]

After deleting the first object, I try to delete third object its throwing error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reason' of undefined
```

I am sure some thing wrong with looping logic but I am not able to get my head around it. Where did I go wrong?

**Update:**

I am trying to delete an element from DOM and its property from Javascript object on click like below:

[image]

Comment: What do you expect to happen to a node after your remove() it?

Comment: try adding typeof condition if (typeof(DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1]) != 'undefined') {

Comment: You must check in your loop [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) before delete

Comment: Your using `delete` on an array?

Comment: @YosvelQuintero What happens when `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` returns false?

Answer (score 1):

If you deleting objects from your DataMixin.data.holidayList, you cannot run through an object from 0 index to Object.keys(DataMixin.data.holidayList).length again. Because you deleted one of its fields (lets say object with index 3), when function will do this part:

```
//i == 3
if(self.deletingId == DataMixin.data.holidayList[i+1].reason){
        //code
}
```

You will get Cannot read property 'reason' of undefined error, cause you deleted this field. You should use this:

```
for (var property in DataMixin.data.holidayList){
  if (DataMixin.data.holidayList.hasOwnProperty(property)){
    //put your code for each property here
  }
}
```

Or you can use  this method:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key,index) {
// key: the name of the object key
// index: the ordinal position of the key within the object 
});
```